# How to print non-ascii character in java?

Tags: java

```
class P1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("¢");
    }
}
```

it comes as only one question mark in command prompt...if you know then please help me out.

Comment: You asked a question, and some people answered. If any of those helped solve your problem, go ahead and accept that answer. If not, comment on that answer explaining why it didn't help. Don't just ask a question and walk away, people are volunteering their time to help you, least you can do is appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

Your terminal does not support UTF-8, you're most likely running Windows. Google to see how to change that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly with the characters your default console/ide can display. Even when displayed on the screen, utf characters need a utf enabled font for them to render correctly.

There are probably Java UTF text editors on GitHub that you could use as a console replacement. Then what you need is an OutputStream that will append to the text editor panel (I created something of this ilk years ago: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/TextAreaOutputStream.java) and then you need to use

```
System.setOut
```

and

```
System.setErr
```

With your Stream